# Flutter - iterate over an asynchrous/future list

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, future

I'm trying to create a list with values obtained by SharedPreferences. However, if I want to use SharedPreference, I've to use async methods / future types and I have no idea how to work with them. I try to iterate over the `sports` list, but it is asynchronous/future. So how do I iterate over it (using map)?

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        Center(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: CarouselSlider(
              options: CarouselOptions(
                height: 565,
                aspectRatio: 16/9,
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
                viewportFraction: .8,
              ),
              items: sportsList.map((i) {
                return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Container(
                    .......
                    .........
                    .......
}


  static Future<bool> initSharedPreference(String key) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    
    return prefs.getBool(key) ?? false;
  }


  Future<List> sportsList() async {
    List sports=[
      await initSharedPreference("test")), 
        ....,
        ....,
        ....
    ];
  }
```

This code doesn't work because of the following:

`The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why causing this problem?**

```
Future<List> sportsList() async {
    List sports=[
      await initSharedPreference("test")), 
        ....,
        ....,
        ....
    ];
  }
```

The above code is not a simple list where the list can be directly rendered. It's returning `Future<List>` which must be fetched as background work.
So Use `FutureBuilder` for it.

FutureBuilder is a one-time call which will run only ones during its lifecycle. So you can rely on it.

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: sportsList(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else {
                List<Widget> list = snapshot.data;
                return CarouselSlider(
                     options: CarouselOptions(
                     height: 565,
                     aspectRatio: 16/9,
                     enlargeCenterPage: true,
                     viewportFraction: .8,
                    ),
                      items: list.map(.....).toList(),
                       
                    );
              }
            })
```

Comment: get data like this List<Widget> list = snapshot.data;

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `FutureBuilder` widget.

In the following example, my asynchronous function is called `getSportsList()` which returns a **future List of Strings** (This could be gotten from SharedPreferences, an API, et cetera. Just make sure it's a future).

```
class FutureList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // THE FUTURE WIDGET

    return FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
      future: getSportsList(), // Add your asynchronous function here
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot){

        List<String> sports = snapshot.data;
        // If there is no data in the snapshot, it is probably loading.
        if(!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator(); 
        // Now add the widget you want to return
        else return CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            height: 565,
            aspectRatio: 16/9,
            enlargeCenterPage: true,
            viewportFraction: .8,
          ),
          items: sportsList.map((String item) {
            return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                .......
                .........
                .......
      },
    );
  }
}
```

A snapshot basically gives info about the future. `snapshot.data` is the result obtained from the future. `snapshot.hasData` tells us whether the future returned a value or not, and there are a couple of other useful methods like snapshot.connectionState or snapshot.hasError for error handling.

For more resources, check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo) by the flutter team. Also check out [the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to find out more

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `FutureBuilder` like this..

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: sportsList(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else {
                return CarouselSlider(
                       items: snapshot.data.map(.....).toList(),
                       //other code
                    );
              }
            })
```